# ¿How to manipulate an image from an array of bytes?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I tried this but when I show the bitmap I can not see anything, what I want is to paint a white outline on the original image

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dog);

 public byte[] myImagetoBytes(Bitmap bitmap){
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }



 byte[] bytes = myImagetoBytes();

 bytes[0] = 1 & 0xff;

 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

 this.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Could you provide a bit more info? Do you see the pry image? What format (I.e how created) is your image?

Comment: it is a png image

Comment: If you want to change the image, you should be operating on the pixels in the `BitMap`.  What your code seems to do is to encode the bitmap to a PNG and then tweak the encoded image.  That's never going to work.

Comment: How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your code is supposed to do, but if you want to draw over a bitmap, you should use `Canvas`. You create it with its constructor:

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
 Paint paint = new Paint();
 paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
 RectF ovalRect = new RectF(0, 0, 10, 10);
 canvas.drawOval(ovalRect, paint);
```